# Get url of the page in php

Tags: php, http-referer

I am working on "Email this page" Popup page. I want to send url of base page as an email, but it should be a popup window.

I have used `HTTP_REFERER`, it is working fine on Firefox, but not working on Internet Explorer.

I am getting the url of current page but I want that url in new popup window page.

Is there any alternative than `HTTP_REFERER`.

Answer (score 2):

On the page you wish to grab the URL of, you can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the requested URI (except the scheme & hostname; in other words, you get the path and query string). Pass this to your other page either using a query string or [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php). The former is preferable, as the latter isn't RESTful. There may be times when it's OK to break REST's rule against server side state, but this probably isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way unless you store it or send it yourself. [This](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2008/11/bug-421-ie-fails-to-pass-http-referer.html) page has one example of how to do it, but only really if you set it beforehand. If the site is your own then you should be ok. If not then you will struggle.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because the `HTTP_REFERER` is sent by the client browser, which means that it's value can be totally manipulated or can even be `null`. This means that this variable isn't very reliable. But if the site is yours, there are other solutions.

You can send the url or any other identification like an ID by QueryStrings. So you'll have the link URL like this `the_send_page_name.php?ref=index.php`

Be aware that this method only works if you're opening the Pop-up in a site that's yours.